# Is Drupal support ORM?

Tags: drupal, orm

I want using drupal for create a website. 
it's very important for me to know drupal is support ORM.
and me know that drupal 7.0 and upper using orm but it's not clear for me .
any one can help me completly to know about drupal orm?
thank you.

Comment: No, Drupal has no ORM as of the current 8.x dev branch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal 7 doesn't use a real ORM like Doctrine, it uses a proprietary [database API as referenced on Drupal.org](https://drupal.org/developing/api/database). So you don't write full SQL statements directly but write it using their API to assemble a query.

So yes it acts as a type of ORM but it's not one that's used outside of the Drupal project.

Examples make things easier: from https://drupal.org/node/310075

Regular SQL:

```
<?php
$result = db_query("SELECT uid, name, status, created, access FROM {users} u WHERE uid <> 0 LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0");
?>
```

Drupal DB API:

```
<?php
// Create an object of type SelectQuery
$query = db_select('users', 'u');
// Add extra detail to this query object: a condition, fields and a range
$query->condition('u.uid', 0, '<>');
$query->fields('u', array('uid', 'name', 'status', 'created', 'access'));
$query->range(0, 50);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the database abstraction layer mentionned in Steve's answer, Drupal 7+ has provide an [Entity API](https://drupal.org/developing/api/entity/7) (completed by the [Entity API module](https://drupal.org/project/entity)). It evolved from the the node system, completed by the CCK module, from Drupal 6. It does provide abstraction to store, [query](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) and [retrieve](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/entity_load/7) data using objects, but the Entity API is not an ORM, and it does no attempt to be one.